# How Can I implement my jQuery code to work on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am very new to jQuery..
I want to implement 2 short jQuery lines of code into my javascript-file to style the border of the item which is shown after searching it. But it doesn't work.
Do I have to include the jQuery library in the js file again or is it enough if I do that once in the html file? Can I use jQuery just in the middle of the JavaScript code without implementing it in some other line?
And: How can I fix my problem above?

```js
function searchRecipe() {
  var searchTerm = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var ul = document.getElementById("recipe-list");
  var li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (var i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    var a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    var recipe = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (recipe.toUpperCase().indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
      // these following 2 lines
      $("div#search #recipe-list li:first-child a").css("border-radius", "5px 5px 0 0");
      $("div#search #recipe-list li:last-child a").css("border-radius", "0 0 5px 5px");
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        ...
        <script src="js/index.js" defer></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- jQuery-Integration -->
      </head>
      <body>
        ...
        <div id="search">
          <input type="text" id="search-bar" autofocus>
          <ul id="recipe-list">
            <li><a href="recipe1.html">Recipe 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="recipe2.html">Recipe 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="recipe3.html">Recipe 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        ...
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're including the jquery library AFTER you include your javascript file. Move the jQuery script tag above it and see if that makes a difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I have to include the jQuery library in the js file again or is it enough if I do that once in the html file? 
-> It's enough if you include your jQuery once in the html file (in the head-tag)

Can I use jQuery just in the middle of the JavaScript code without implementing it in some other line? 
-> Yes, but make sure you are loading JQuery before the other javascripts which are containing JQuery-code. You could try moving your code with JQuery in the body-tag.

And: How can I fix my problem above?
-> Is the web-console throwing any errors? Seeing the error message would also help.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was, that I didn't loaded JQuery before the javaScript-file in head-tag.. this fixed my problem.